# Recursive mean in R

Tags: r, recursion, mean

How would I for a column in a dataframe calculate the mean recursively? So for the dataframe

```
   X1 <- runif(50, 0, 1)

   X2 <- runif(50, 0, 10) 


   df <- data.frame(X1,X2)
```

calculate the means for column 2 as the mean including line 1, then the mean including the lines 1-2, then the mean including lines 1-3 and so on. I only found the function rapply which only works for lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two possible options :

```
# generic, not very efficient but you can use it to compute other functions, not only mean
DF$recursiveMean <- sapply(1:nrow(DF),function(i) mean(DF$X2[1:i]))
# very efficient way, but it only computes the mean
DF$recursiveMean <- cumsum(DF$X2)/1:nrow(DF)
```

Comment: The first option is great, since I also want to use other functions, thanks!

Comment: @Julia If this is the solution you need, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the column `CumMean`

```
df$CumSum <- cumsum(df$X2)
df$CumMean <- df$CumSum / 1:nrow(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets what you want with [`dplyr`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

```r
library(dplyr)

X1 <- runif(50, 0, 1)
X2 <- runif(50, 0, 10) 

df <- data_frame(X1,X2)

df %>% 
  mutate(row_sum = X1 + X2,
         # cumulative sum of the sum of X1 and X2
         cum_sum = cumsum(row_sum), 
         # The number of rows to be included in the recursive mean times 
         # the number of original columns included (X1 and X2)
         denom = seq_along(X1) * 2, 
         # the final recursive mean
         rec_mean = cum_sum / denom) 

#> # A tibble: 50 x 6
#>            X1       X2  row_sum   cum_sum denom  rec_mean
#>         <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1  0.74556627 1.218812 1.964378  1.964378     2 0.9821891
#> 2  0.52028772 2.118244 2.638532  4.602910     4 1.1507275
#> 3  0.82827969 5.964946 6.793226 11.396136     6 1.8993560
#> 4  0.23165987 7.785801 8.017461 19.413597     8 2.4266997
#> 5  0.94498383 4.913119 5.858103 25.271700    10 2.5271700
#> 6  0.97138884 2.455740 3.427128 28.698828    12 2.3915690
#> 7  0.65725366 6.619548 7.276801 35.975630    14 2.5696878
#> 8  0.58452486 8.555269 9.139794 45.115424    16 2.8197140
#> 9  0.06390008 1.881750 1.945650 47.061074    18 2.6145041
#> 10 0.95357395 7.336068 8.289642 55.350716    20 2.7675358
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```